# Trying to display count on webpage for how many values are selected from multiple selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am newer to Javascript, and have a website that is currently setup so the user can select multiple options and it will add their values together. I am trying to make it give a count of how many of the options they have selected

```js
// Call out all the functions for the calculations
$(function() {
  var fields = $('option');
  $('#form1 :input').change(calculate)
  $("#form1 option").text(function(i, t) {
    if (this.value !== "0")
      return t + " - " + this.value
  })
  // Do the calculations
  function calculate() {
    var severity = 0;
    fields.each(function() {
      if (this.selected) {
        severity += +$(this).val();
      }
    })
    $('#severity').html(numberWithCommas(severity.toFixed(0)));
  }
})
// Because Javascript hates commas
function numberWithCommas(x) {
  return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" method="post" action="">
  <select name="DMA" multiple id="DMA">
    <option value="1" label="1">1</option>
    <option value="2" label="2">2</option>
    <option value="3" label="3">3</option>
    <option value="4" label="4">4</option>
  </select>
</form>
You have selected "n" options with a total value of <u id="severity"></u>
```

I want the last portion of HTML to show the total items selected in the "n" field. I suspect I will just need to replace the "n" with something similar to the  I have which gives a total of all values selcted from the table.

Hopefully I have been clear on what I am trying to do, please let me know if there are any additional questions. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Replace `"n"` with `<span id="count">0</span>` and increase a second var by 1 inside `if (this.selected) {`, then use the exact same mechanism you used for the severity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Add a section to store the selected options, i.e: `<span id="count">0</span>`.
- Use the following to count the selected options `$(this).children(':selected').length`

```js
// Call out all the functions for the calculations
$(function() {
  var fields = $('option');
  $('#form1 :input').change(calculate)
  $("#form1 option").text(function(i, t) {
    if (this.value !== "0")
      return t + " - " + this.value
  })
  // Do the calculations
  function calculate() {
    var severity = 0;
    fields.each(function() {
      if (this.selected) {
        severity += +$(this).val();
      }
    })
    $('#severity').html(numberWithCommas(severity.toFixed(0)));
    
    $('#count').html($(this).children(':selected').length);
  }
})
// Because Javascript hates commas
function numberWithCommas(x) {
  return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" method="post" action="">
  <select name="DMA" multiple id="DMA">
    <option value="1" label="1">1</option>
    <option value="2" label="2">2</option>
    <option value="3" label="3">3</option>
    <option value="4" label="4">4</option>
  </select>
</form>
You have selected <span id="count">0</span> options with a total value of <u id="severity"></u>
```

Comment: Thanks, this did exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think that someone likes complicated solutions..

```js
$('#DMA').on('input',function(){
    var $el=$(this).find(':selected');
    var count=0;
    $el.each(function(){
        count+=parseFloat($(this).val().replace(',', '.'))
    });
    $('#severity').html(count);
    $('#amount').html($el.length)
}).trigger('input')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" method="post" action="">
  <select name="DMA" multiple id="DMA">
    <option value="1" label="1">1</option>
    <option value="2,5" label="2">2</option>
    <option value="3.2" label="3">3</option>
    <option value="4" label="4">4</option>
  </select>
</form>
You have selected <u id="amount"></u> options with a total value of <u id="severity"></u>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just count up the numer of selected items (in `calculate()` method) and afterwards let jQuery display the value in an html element:

```js
// Call out all the functions for the calculations
$(function() {
  var fields = $('option');
  $('#form1 :input').change(calculate)
  $("#form1 option").text(function(i, t) {
    if (this.value !== "0")
      return t + " - " + this.value
  })
  // Do the calculations
  function calculate() {
    var severity = 0;
    var count = 0
    fields.each(function() {
      if (this.selected) {
        severity += +$(this).val();
        count++
      }
    })
    $('#severity').html(numberWithCommas(severity.toFixed(0)));
    $('#amount').html(count);
  }
})
// Because Javascript hates commas
function numberWithCommas(x) {
  return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" method="post" action="">
  <select name="DMA" multiple id="DMA">
    <option value="1" label="1">1</option>
    <option value="2" label="2">2</option>
    <option value="3" label="3">3</option>
    <option value="4" label="4">4</option>
  </select>
</form>
You have selected <u id="amount"></u> options with a total value of <u id="severity"></u>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a proper container in your html to store the value:

   `<span id="n">COUNT</span>`
2. Count all the selected options using jQuery:

   `var n = $('#DMA option:selected').length`
3. Replace the value of the container with the count:

   `$('span#n').val( n );`

Putting it all together,

**HTML:**

```
You have selected <span id="n"></span> options with a total value of <u id="severity"></u>
```

**JavaScript (jQuery):**

`$('span#n').val( $('#DMA option:selected').length );`